# I want to open a file for reading in the constructor. The file should be readable in any method without creating another reader object

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

The constructor opens a file for reading. I have a method called getNext() which returns the next line of the file in a String array. However it says that the BufferedReader object in already created in the constructor cannot be found
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

```
public class SNIDDb
{
  private char delimiter;
  private String name;

  public SNIDDb(String name, char delimiter)
  {
    this.name=name;
    this.delimiter=delimiter;
    try
    {
      FileReader fr= new FileReader(name);
      BufferedReader br= new BufferReader(fr);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      System.out.print(e.getMessage());
    }
  }

  public Boolean hasNext() throws Exception
  {
    return !(br.readLine()==null); 
  }

  public String[] getNext() throws Exception
  {
    String c_line="";
    c_line=br.readLine();
    String[] n_line=c_line.split(delimiter);
    return n_line;
  }

  public void rewrite() throws Exception
  {
    br.close();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(name));
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`br` is a local variable only available for use inside the constructor. You should make it an instance member variable like `delimiter` and `name`.

Comment: Thanks alot this helped with my problem